# "Be an average height" vs. "be the average height"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Would you please tell me if I need to use *an* or *the* in before *average* in the context below?

> 176cm is **an**/**the** average height for men in the US.

I've heard both. Are both acceptable? If so, can you tell me what is the slight difference between them.

Comment: What do you think the answer is? Why do you think that? Why are you unsure?

Comment: I'm unsure because I've heard both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say "176cm is **the** average height for men in the US."

The general pattern would be

"[Measurement] is **the** average height for [group A]"

You would use "an average height" in other contexts; for example, after the verb *have*:

"[Group A] have **an** average height of [measurement]"

Answer (score 1):

When you use 'a' rather than 'the', it seems that you want to say one of the multiple choices.

> An average height of men (one of the average height of men), but one
> of what?

On the other hand when you say: The average height of men, you mean there is only one average and you mention the value.

I also think you have to re-order the statement as follows:

> The average height of men in the US is 176 cm.

Therefore, if you don't want to change the order, it would be like this:

> 176 cm is the average height of men in the US.